# CosmosDB fails to Deserialize Object after moving to new Assembly

Tags: json.net, botframework, azure-cosmosdb

I am using CosmosDB to store my BotState and ConversationState.  Now that my codebase has grown, we have started to refactor, and we moved some objects into a common library and such.

After doing so, making the call

```
userData = await _botAccessors.BotStateAccessor.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new UserData(), cancellationToken);
```

fails with the following exception

```
Error resolving type specified in JSON '...'. Path '['BotAccessors.BotState'].ConversationContext.PreviousResponses.$values[0].channelData.$type'.
```

I have looked in the Document of the CosmosDB and I see the problem.

I have tried to set the TypeNameHandling and TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling as such

```
var requestOptions = new RequestOptions
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None, TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Simple }
    };
```

when creating the CosmosDbStorageOptions, but this does not allow me to resolve the issue.

Not sure what to try next.

Comment: You might need to write your own `ISerializationBinder` mapping the old type name + namespace + assembly name(s) to the new.  See https://thomaslevesque.com/2019/10/14/handling-type-hierarchies-in-cosmos-db-part1/ and https://thomaslevesque.com/2019/10/15/handling-type-hierarchies-in-cosmos-db-part-2/

Comment: Did you find my answer sufficient? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 0):

This is [a bug in the v2 of Azure Cosmos DocumentDB Client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/351) and has been for awhile. Reviewing that issue, it doesn't appear that they plan to fix it in v2 and have instead opted to fix it in v3. Unfortunately:

- Bot Framework doesn't plan to update `CosmosDbStorage` to v3 since `CosmosDbPartitionedStorage` was released in its place.
- Currently, `CosmosDbPartitionedStorage` is not compatible with non-partitioned databases. A migration plan and backwards-compatibility is currently being discussed but may not be released soon.

So, your only option right now is to basically clone [`CosmosDbStorage`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/CosmosDbStorage.cs), calling it something like `NiteLordsCosmosDbStorage`, and performing JSON serialization in the `ReadAsync()` or `WriteAsync()` methods, as necessary.